# all the link in my php form direct to the form action

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

This is my following codes..

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="tambah_gps" name="tambah_gps" method="POST" action="../controller/add_gps.php">
              <table>
                <tr style="height:40px">
                  <td>Nama User</td>
                  <td style="width:20px"> : </td>
                  <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nama_user" placeholder=" User Name" style="width:300px" readonly></td>
                  <td>&nbsp&nbsp<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick=window.open("pilih_user.php","Ratting","width=1000,height=400,left=200,");><button class="btn btn-primary">Choose User</button></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:40px">
                  <td>Vehicle ID</td>
                  <td style="width:20px"> : </td>
                  <td colspan="2"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="no_polisi" placeholder=" Nomor Polisi Kendaraan"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:40px">
                  <td>Car brand</td>
                  <td style="width:20px"> : </td>
                  <td colspan="2"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="merk_mobil" placeholder=" Merk Mobil"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:40px">
                  <td>Color</td>
                  <td style="width:20px"> : </td>
                  <td colspan="2"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="warna" placeholder=" Warna"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:40px">
                  <td>GPS Number</td>
                  <td style="width:20px"> : </td>
                            <td colspan="2"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="no_telp_gps" placeholder=" nomor telepon GPS"><td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:40px">
                  <td>Time Zone/td>
                  <td style="width:20px"> : </td>
                  <td colspan="2"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="zona_waktu" value="GMT (Default)" placeholder=" Zona Waktu" readonly></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
<form>
```

The form I made has 3 buttons : 1 Button Save, 1 Button Cancel, and 1 button to choose User Name.. if the button to choose user name clicked, it will open new window that containing user list. the button works pretty well. but whenever it clicked the page always directed to the form action (just like when you click the save button). Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code? Thank you...

Comment: you have them both as the btn btn-primary, try changing one of them and see what happens

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your code. that's just how html forms behave. you click a button inside the form, it's going to submit that form.

Comment: @jim: css classes have no bearing on what happens when you click a button. they're just styling rules...

Comment: Move the button outside of the form and then echo its selected value to a field inside the form.

Comment: Make your button an `<a></a>` tag instead of that button and style it as a button. Buttons tend to behave as submitters in html forms, although in your case it shouldn't. Your code looks fine.

Comment: @Dorvalla I think your suggestion is the best choice to solve my problem.. Thank you...

Comment: @Dorvalla The code above is badly broken and cannot pass basic validation by W3C validator. It is a bit of a stretch to expect browsers to "guess" the intent of this html when standard is not followed.

Comment: I was, more refering, as in code looks fine, towards the calls, not towards validation of w3c. @user3713667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you use your <button> inside of <a> where latter has javascript:void(0) as href. If href is not needed then there no point to put <a> around <button>.

Second &nbps entity MUST end with ;

Third javascript in onclick must be enclosed by " . Single quotes should be used within javascript statement.

And last: you must tell <button> to be exactly what you want it to be: just button! by using type='button'

Therefore the line for your "Choose User" button looks as follows:

```
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="window.open('pilih_user.php','Ratting','width=1000,height=400,left=200');">Choose User</button></a></td>
```